# Is there a way to get to the original http post message from onfailure of okhttp3?

Tags: java, okhttp

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://example.com")
            .post(RequestBody.create("foo",MediaType.get("text/plain")))
            .build();
```

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
             
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    RequestBody b = call.request().body();
                    String t= b.toString(); ??? <-How would I get the original message?
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    //do something
                     
                }
            });
```

On failure I am trying to save the original message that I sent.

I looked through the functions and I don't seem to be able to figure out how to get the original message I sent in the callback. Is there a way to get the message back?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is looking for this:

```
Buffer b = new Buffer();
call.request().body().writeTo(b)
String result=b.readString(Charset.defaultCharset()); //Change this to whatever your character set is
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your answer, you could define an [`Interceptor`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/) and log those requests who failed. This as example, without any conditions:

```
class ReqInterceptor implements Interceptor 
{
   @Override
   public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException
   {
     Request request = chain.request();  // original Request
     logger.info(String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
                 request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));

     Response response = chain.proceed(request);
     logger.info(String.format("Received response for %s %s",
                 response.request().url(), response.headers()));
   
     return response;
   }
}
```

Then in the client, something like:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new ReqInterceptor()) //<--this
            .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://example.com")
        .post(RequestBody.create("foo",MediaType.get("text/plain")))
        .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response.body().close();
```

---

There are two types and even [two defined implementations](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/logging-interceptor/) for `Interceptor`, but the network one would provide the same data that is transmitted by the wire, so you may choose this if exact info is needed:

[image]